# How can I compile & and run an ESQL/C program on Linux Platform?

Tags: c, compilation, informix, embedded-sql

I have checked the IBM official site for ESQL/C programming guide. I didn't find exact commands to compile and run. Do I need to install any packages to run? Can anyone tell me the commands to run these in Ubuntu?

Comment: Note that there are 2 `esqlc` programs, one from Informix (input files ending with .ec) and one from Ingres II (input files ending with .sc).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ESQL/C (Embedded SQL in C) uses C code for the bulk of the code, but uses special markers (either `$` in Informix ESQL/C or `EXEC SQL` in both standard and Informix ESQL/C) to indicate where SQL statements need preprocessing to be converted into an appropriate series of C library function calls and C variable definitions, etc.  The `esql` script is the compiler that automatically converts Informix ESQL/C source into first C and then object code and an executable (under options that are mainly the same as the C compiler's options, most of which are passed to the C compiler unchanged).

You need to have the Informix ClientSDK (CSDK) installed to be able to compile ESQL/C programs.  That is installed by default when the server is installed, so the chances are you're OK if you're on a machine with a working Informix server on it (if it also has a working C compiler and development environment).  It is also available as a separate standalone product which you could install if you don't have, and don't want, an Informix server on your machine.  There are advantages for testing if the server is local (quicker access, and less danger of damaging production systems, amongst others).

Assuming you have got CSDK installed, you need to set the environment variable `INFORMIXDIR` to point where the software is installed (unless you chose to install it in `/usr/informix` or create a symlink `/usr/informix` that points to to where CSDK is installed).  You'll also want to add `$INFORMIXDIR/bin` to your PATH.  You're now ready to compile:

- Compile `.ec` (ESQL/C source) files to object with the `esql` command:

  ```
  esql -c esqlc_source.ec
  ```

  Add other C compiler options as needed.  Note that `-g` is intercepted by the `esql` script and you have to work hard to get it passed to the C compiler.
- Consider compiling `.c` (C source) files that use an ESQL/C header with the `esql` script too.  This will pass the correct directory for the headers to the C compiler automatically.  More likely, you'll use:

  ```
  ${CC} -c c_source.c -I${INFORMIXDIR}/incl/esql
  ```
- For linking, use the `esql` script to do it.  It will provide the correct libraries (and object files) to the compiler, which it will invoke as the linker:

  ```
  esql -o program c_source.o esqlc_source.o
  ```

  You can add other libraries and library directories as usual.

You have the program compiled; now you need to run it.  The chances are that you won't find the libraries automatically.  You will need to think about adding some directories to either `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` or modify `/etc/ld.so.conf` to pick up the extra directories, or create symlinks to the Informix libraries from a place that will be picked up automatically (e.g. `/usr/lib` or `/usr/lib64`, or perhaps `/usr/local/lib`) to where the libraries are installed.

You need to add at minimum:

- `$INFORMIXDIR/lib`
- `$INFORMIXDIR/lib/esql`

Under some circumstances, you may need to add other library directories found under `$INFORMIXDIR/lib` as well, but usually not.

You should then be able to run the program.  Using `ldd program` will let you know when you've got the settings right.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I don't want to install Informix server on my machine. How can I be able to do so? @JonathanLeffler

Comment: Download Informix CSDK from an IBM/Informix download site.  That gets tricky; I'm an insider and get things through the back door.  However, a Google search on 'ibm informix clientsdk download' shows a number of plausible looking IBM sites.  You could look at the IIUG (International Informix User Group) site too (http://www.iiug.org/) — it may be available there.  Membership is free.  CSDK is available free anyway; the server is a chargeable item, though there are free trial configurations.

Comment: This is the official IBM software download site for all no-charge products - https://www-01.ibm.com/marketing/iwm/tnd/nochargesearchquery.jsp

Comment: Thanks, @PradeepNatarajan.

Comment: Thanks @PradeepNatarajan